# Backend project on swift 5.8 and vapor

Tags: ios, swift, macos, backend, vapor

I'm taking a vapor video course. I write code strictly according to it, and when I try to send a Post request (by postman), get a custom error code. In the course, everything is fine and it seems that the code is identical. Does anyone know what to do ?

```
import Foundation
import Fluent
import Vapor


struct ProductsController: RouteCollection {
    func boot(routes: Vapor.RoutesBuilder) throws {
        let productsGroup = routes.grouped("products")
        productsGroup.post(use: createHandler)
        productsGroup.get(use: getAllHandler)
    }
    
    func createHandler(_ req: Request) async throws -> Product {
        guard let product = try? req.content.decode(Product.self) else {
            throw Abort(.custom(code: 499, reasonPhrase: "Не получилось декодировать контент в модель продукта"))
        }
        
        try await product.save(on: req.db)
        return product
    }
    
    func getAllHandler(_ req: Request) async throws -> [Product] {
        let products = try await Product.query(on: req.db).all()
        return products
    }
}
```

There is a connection in the routes.swift file.

```
import Fluent
import Vapor

func routes(_ app: Application) throws {
    
    try app.register(collection: ProductsController())
    
}
```

And here is the
[code from the video course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6QVT.jpg)

Comment: What is the request you are making? What is the error or response? Review those details to help figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Please edit your code to include the HTML form and the Product struct definition.

Comment: As the question is regarding a request please share the request and the error response you're getting. The code itself is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost certain your decode is failing due to one or more of the following differences between your Product structure fields and the HTML form’s fields. Check:

1. HTML name tags exist for every field in Product.
2. If a form input may be null then the struct field definition is optional.
3. The form input type is appropriate. For example, decoding dates and integers may be easier done as strings and then post-process.

You can work out which ones are failing by commenting out the struct fields and checking an empty struct decodes. Then uncomment one-by-one until you hit the error again.